# Showing menu bar on Visualforce pages with Lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

How can I enable the quick access toolbar / menu bar on the vf page once I enable the new lightning experience.

I see 2 relevant options which I thought would let me enable the menu bar,and set all the 2 options to true yet I do not see the menu bar on the side.

1) Showheader

2) Sidebar

[image]

Comment: Based on this trailhead tutorial Salesforce Classic Header and Sidebar are Always Suppressed, if this is true how would i navigate to the home page from a VF page? Ah this is a learning nightmare :(
 https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_known_issues

Comment: I have found that navigating to what were tabs (not shown in sidebar) is cumbersome in the lightening Ui. Click apps, click on the app that includes the tab ( if u remember) then on app home click tab. Repeat every time. Desktop was not meant to be a mobile platform and to me at least the navigation of lightning requires the user to embrace change when most are not

Comment: @eric Lighting experience is a nightmare :(. I do not want to switch there anytime sooner, but I do not want to be left behind too.

Comment: I agree. I do not see it being adopted by enterprise customers in the near future. Just the fact the VF is castrated alone kills it for me. Heck, the iframe killed the ability for VF to perform oAuth into SF completely. I could go on and on. And I agree about the not wanting to be left behind. I bet many of us are thinking the same thing.